# round to show one decimal place for the cylinder output

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How would I round the answer so one decimal place would be displayed in the output? For example: If the radius were to be 8 the output would be 1005.3. As of right now it just displays 1005

```
import math 
import sqrt
import math

def find_volume(radius, height):
    return pi * radius * radius * height

def print_results (radius,height):
    print 'Volume = '

def find_surface_area(radius, height):
     return 2 * math.pi * radius * height + 2 * math.pi * 
     math.pow(radius,2)

def print_results (radius,height):
    print 'Surface = '

def main():
    radius = float(input("Enter value for a Radius: "))
    height = float(input("Enter value for a Height: "))
    print("Cylinder volume: %d" % (find_volume(radius, height)))
    print("Cylinder surface area: %d" % (find_surface_area(radius,height))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: python has a `round(number,num_digits)` method builtin

Comment: what line of code would I put this under?

Comment: @Shriya Wherever you want to round off your number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
res = 1005.3    
print('%.3f' %res)
# output : 1005.300
```

Answer (score 1):

This question may be of help: [Python 2.7: %d, %s, and float()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215242/python-2-7-d-s-and-float)

When you are printing your result, you are using `%d` which stands for an integer. Instead try `%10.1f`.

Answer (score 1):

First there are some Syntax Errors:

`print 'Surface = '` should be `print('Surface= ')` if you are using python 3 else this is right but then the print statements in  your main functions are wrong

Also you are missing a parentheses in your last print statement in the main function and in the `find_volume` function you are using `pi` which gives also a error you have to use `math.pi` if you do not do `from math import pi`.
In addition you don't have to import math twice

If you want a float with 1 decimal place you have to use `%f % round(find_surface_area(radius,height),1))` but this gives, when radius is 8 and height is 3, `552.900000` but you can use .format{} instead wich works correctly for me (i'm on python 3)

the code below should work

```
import math

def find_volume(radius, height):

    return round(math.pi * radius * radius * height,1)

def print_results (radius,height):

   print('Volume = ')

def find_surface_area(radius, height):

   return round(2 * math.pi * radius * height + 2 * math.pi * math.pow(radius,2), 1)

def print_results (radius,height):

     print('Surface = ')

def main():

    radius = float(input("Enter value for a Radius: "))

    height = float(input("Enter value for a Height: "))

    print("Cylinder volume: {}".format(find_volume(radius, height)))

    print("Cylinder surface area: {}".format(find_surface_area(radius, height)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like :

```
>>> a=165.1984965468
>>> "%.2f" % round(a,2)
'165.20'
```

**EDIT**

```
>>> "%.1f" % round(a,1)
'165.2'
```

Comment: My expected output would need to be 165.2 since my teacher specifically asked for 1 decimal point only.

Comment: see **EDIT** in my post