# What is the modern print version of %6.4f?

Tags: python, string, printing

For older version of Python, one can print the string as such:

```
>>> print('X = %6.4f' % 12312312.423141)
X = 12312312.4231
```

And in Python < 3.6, putting a float into a formatted string and printing the string. In modern python, one could have done:

```
>>> print('X = {num}'.format(num=round(12312312.423141, 4)))
X = 12312312.4231
```

But that's explicitly rounding the float to 4 decimal points. Is there a way to print the float as in the old way by stating the 6-place field to the 4 decimal points? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15215445/610569

For Python > 3.6, **how about fstring? Would it look like this?**

```
>>> num=12312312.423141
>>> print(f'X = {num:6.4f}')
```

Comment: `f'X = {num:6.4f}'` in python 3.6 is the same as `'X = {num:6.4f}.format(num)'`.

Comment: how about `print('X = {num:6.4f}'.format(num=12312312.423141) )`?

Comment: Oh you'd really enjoy this https://pyformat.info

Comment: What is your problem with this solution: `print(f'X = {num:6.4f}')`?

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace, that's awesome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format a decimal to always show 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, but to answer the question in the title:

The new python3.6 version of `'X = %6.4f' % 12312312.423141` is, as you said `f'X = {12312312.423141:6.4f}'`

The below python3.6 version is `'X = {num:6.4f}'.format(num=12312312.423141)`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I can use the `%6.4f` in the `str.format()` and `f'...'` string too.

In Python >= 3.6:

```
>>> num=12312312.423141
>>> 'X = %6.4f' % num == 'X = {num:6.4f}'.format(num=num) == f'X = {num:6.4f}'
True

>>> print('X = %6.4f' % num)
X = 12312312.4231

>>> print('X = {num:6.4f}'.format(num=num))
X = 12312312.4231

>>> print(f'X = {num:6.4f}')
X = 12312312.4231
```

And the docs:

- https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting
- https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting